# Nativescript extending java class generates unknown constructors

Tags: java, typescript, nativescript, marshalling

I`m developing a plugin that uses a JAR library with an abstract class that contains two simple constructors:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {

    public AbstractClass(int param1) {}       

    public AbstractClass(int param1, String param2) {}
}
```

In my plugin I have defined java typing file for TypeScript, and in the actual plugin I`m extending the java abstract class like in the [DOCS](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/binding-generator/extend-class-interface). However, when I try to run the demo app on my device gradle fails to build with the following error:

```
No suitable constructor found for AbstractClass(String, int, String)
      super(param_0, param_1, param_2);
constructor AbstractClass.AbstractClass(int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor AbstractClass.AbstractClass(String,int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int super(param_0);
```

My TypeScript code looks like that:

```
export class MyClass extends org.library.AbstractClass {
  static constructorCalled: boolean = false;

  constructor() {
    super();
    MyClass.constructorCalled = true;

    return global.__native(this);
  }
}
```

But when I looked in the file that is generated by {NS}, there are three constructors with (int), (String) and (String, int, String), which is non-sense.

Comment: You have created an abstract class with constructors excepting 1 or 2 arguments but you are calling the super method with no arguments?

Comment: @Manoj If you look at the docs (https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/binding-generator/extend-class-interface) this is how you extend the parent class

Comment: Even in docs as you could see, while extending Button it's called with one parameter (`super(context)`) because it needs one parameter to be initialised.

Comment: @Manoj in the button example there is a Javascript and TypeScript equivalent, which is:        class MyButton extends android.widget.Button {
    static constructorCalled: boolean = false;
    // constructor
    constructor() {
        super();
        MyButton.constructorCalled = true;

        // necessary when extending TypeScript constructors
        return global.__native(this);
    }

    setEnabled(enabled : boolean): void {
        this.super.setEnabled(enabled);
    }
}

let btn = new MyButton(context);

Comment: I suspect the documentation is wrong then. Your class doesn't have a constructor without arguments. Within JavaScript you will have only one constructor always, based on the number of arguments you might decide how many arguments you want to pass to the native constructor as Java supports method / constructor overloading. The example given in docs would fail if you do not pass context to the super call (TypeScript).

Comment: @Manoj I agree that {NS}documentation could be improved... but the thing is it does not work with their provided example nor it does not work if I pass the arguments into the super class..